# Unable to launch Spyder after installing Anaconda 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

**Problem Description**
I am unable to launch Spyder after I installed Anaconda. It seems like Spyder is running in the background but it is not opening in the upfront.

**What is the expected output? What do you see instead?**
Spyder should open so that I can practice machine learning but it is not happening.

**Versions**

> Spyder version: 3.2.8
>   Python version: 3.6.5
>   Qt version: 5.9.5
>   PyQt version: 5.9.2
>   Operating System name/version: Windows 10

**Steps I Took to Solve the Issue**
I executed the following code in Anoconda Prompt but that didn't work. I have added the screenshots of the error output which I got.
I executed this code in anaconda Prompt `pip install pywt5`.
**Expected Outcome**
Spyder should launch and the editor will appear on the screen.
**Actual Outcome**
Some error output mentioned in the First image.

Further, I uninstalled and reinstalled the Anaconda and executed the code in Anaconda Prompt `conda update spyder`.

**Expected Outcome**
Spyder should launch and the editor will appear on the screen.

**Actual Outcome**
Some error output mentioned in the other two images.

Also, I do not have any prior knowledge of programming. I just started to learn the basics of Machine Learning and found myself stuck in the very beginning. I tried executing the commands `pip install pyqt5` and `conda install -f zeromq pyzmq`, this also didn't solve the issue. I have attached the screenshots of the Anaconda Prompt after writing these codes.

Comment: You have not actually attached any error messages. But when you do: Don't add them as images, copy and paste them as **text**, then highlight them and click the `{}` to format them as "code", which makes them easier to read

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The pictures the OP was referring to were posted in our issues tracker, specifically [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7778). We're trying to help him there.

Comment: @AmitKumar, please wait for us to come back to you instead of reposting the same question here.